General solution of a non-linear ODE
How to solve (at least symbolically) a second-order non-linear ODE of the form:
$$ \dfrac{d^2u}{dt^2} = t^n f(u) $$
where $n$ is a real number?
For $n=0$, the solution is straightforward. Considering $\frac{du}{dt} = \dot{u}$, one finds:
$$ t = t_0 \pm \int \left[2 \int f(u) \, du + \text{constant}\right]^{-1/2} \, du $$
But for a general $n \neq 0$, how can this be solved?
My thought: Is there any way to reduce it to a first-order non-linear ODE and then somehow solve it?

Mathematica fails to find a solution for generic $f(u)$ if $n=1,2$ are attempted. There are presumably solvable cases of $f(u)$ but this doesn't bode well for finding a generic approach.

Maybe considering an homogeneous function of degree $n$ could give us some interesting propertins, so consider a function $f$ such that for all $t>0$ we have $f(t,u)=t^nf(u)$.

For the case $f(u)=u$:
$$u(t)=c_{1} \sqrt{t}\cdot I_{\frac{1}{n+2}} \left(\frac{2 t^{\frac{n}{2}+1}}{n+2}\right)+c_{2} \sqrt{t}\cdot K_{\frac{1}{n+2}} \left(\frac{2 t^{\frac{n}{2}+1}}{n+2}\right)$$
$I_n(z)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.
$K_n(z)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

This should not be considered an answer but more like a list of interesting solutions.

For the case $f(u)=u$, as written by @gpmath in the comment, we have
$$
u(t)=c_1\,\sqrt{t}\,\mathrm{I}_{\frac{1}{n + 2}}\left(\frac{2\,t^{\frac{n}{2} + 1}}{n + 2}\right) + c_2\,\sqrt{t}\,\mathrm{K}_{\frac{1}{n+2}}\left(\frac{2\,t^{\frac{n}{2} + 1}}{n + 2}\right)
$$
where $\mathrm{I}_n(z)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind while $\mathrm{K}_n(z)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Playing with Matlab, we have that for a general linear function $f(u)=m\,u+q$ with $m,\,q\in\mathbb{R}$ we get this absolute monstrosity
$$
u(t)=
c_{1}\,\sqrt{t}\,{\mathrm{J}}_{\frac{1}{n+2}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{m}\,t^{\frac{n}{2}+1}\,2{}\mathrm{i}}{n+2}\right)+c_{2}\,\sqrt{t}\,{\mathrm{Y}}_{\frac{1}{n+2}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{m}\,t^{\frac{n}{2}+1}\,2{}\mathrm{i}}{n+2}\right)+\sqrt{t}\,{\mathrm{J}}_{\frac{1}{n+2}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{m}\,t^{\frac{n}{2}+1}\,2{}\mathrm{i}}{n+2}\right)\,\int \frac{q\,t^{n/2}\,{\mathrm{Y}}_{\frac{1}{n+2}}\left(\frac{2\,\sqrt{-m}\,t^{\frac{n}{2}+1}}{n+2}\right)\,\sqrt{-\frac{1}{m\,t}}}{{\mathrm{J}}_{\frac{1}{n+2}}\left(\frac{2\,\sqrt{-m}\,t^{\frac{n}{2}+1}}{n+2}\right)\,{\mathrm{Y}}_{\frac{n+3}{n+2}}\left(\frac{2\,\sqrt{-m}\,t^{\frac{n}{2}+1}}{n+2}\right)-{\mathrm{Y}}_{\frac{1}{n+2}}\left(\frac{2\,\sqrt{-m}\,t^{\frac{n}{2}+1}}{n+2}\right)\,{\mathrm{J}}_{\frac{n+3}{n+2}}\left(\frac{2\,\sqrt{-m}\,t^{\frac{n}{2}+1}}{n+2}\right)} \,d t-\sqrt{t}\,{\mathrm{Y}}_{\frac{1}{n+2}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{m}\,t^{\frac{n}{2}+1}\,2{}\mathrm{i}}{n+2}\right)\,\int \frac{q\,t^{n/2}\,{\mathrm{J}}_{\frac{1}{n+2}}\left(\frac{2\,\sqrt{-m}\,t^{\frac{n}{2}+1}}{n+2}\right)\,\sqrt{-\frac{1}{m\,t}}}{{\mathrm{J}}_{\frac{1}{n+2}}\left(\frac{2\,\sqrt{-m}\,t^{\frac{n}{2}+1}}{n+2}\right)\,{\mathrm{Y}}_{\frac{n+3}{n+2}}\left(\frac{2\,\sqrt{-m}\,t^{\frac{n}{2}+1}}{n+2}\right)-{\mathrm{Y}}_{\frac{1}{n+2}}\left(\frac{2\,\sqrt{-m}\,t^{\frac{n}{2}+1}}{n+2}\right)\,{\mathrm{J}}_{\frac{n+3}{n+2}}\left(\frac{2\,\sqrt{-m}\,t^{\frac{n}{2}+1}}{n+2}\right)} \,d t
$$
where $\mathrm{J}_n(z)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind while $\mathrm{Y}_n(z)$ is the Bessel function of the second kind.

Interestingly, Matlab is not able to solve this ode for $f(u)=\sin(u),\,f(u)=\cos(u),\,f(u)=\arctan(u),\,f(u)=u^2,\,f(u)=e^u,\,f(u)=\sinh(u),\,f(u)=\cosh(u),\,f(u)=\ln(u),\,f(u)=\sqrt{u^2}$

If $f(u)=u'$
$$
u(t)=c_{1}+\frac{c_{2}\,{\left(-\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)}^{\frac{n}{n+1}}\,\left(n+1\right)\,\Gamma \left(1-\frac{n}{n+1},-\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)}{{\left(t^{n+1}\right)}^{\frac{n}{n+1}}}
$$
where $\Gamma(s,z)$ is the incomplete Gamma function.



I am starting to think that the equation has solution only if $f(u)$ is linear. Yet, i am really far away to prove it.
